# How to change adobe air application's default install directory?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I need to change the default install directory from "C:\Program files" to "C:\Directory..\folderXX.."
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's likely that this is not possible. Adobe follows extremely strict security protocols and installing outside of the Program Files folder seems like something they would try to prevent (speaking as a long-time Flash developer who has watched Adobe really beef up their security over the years)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are installing your app for the first time, the user can choose were they want to install the app which defaults to the standard directories, but can be changed by the user.

Subsequent installs overwrite the previous install and don't allow you to choose. You'd have to uninstall first.

If you are saying you want to hardcode where the user installs, I don't think that's possible. You'd have to write your own installer. You could use the standard installer and just make a strong recommendation where the user should stick it in your installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google gave me this: [Specifying a custom install folder for an application in Adobe AIR](http://airexamples.com/2008/12/30/specifying-a-custom-install-folder-for-an-application-in-adobe-air/)

So, all you have to do is manipulate the application descriptor xml of your project, specifcally the node  `< installFolder>Your/Desired/Path< /installFolder>`

Comment: sorry but it's not the requirement, <installFolder> change only the folders inside "Program Files", but i want to change the default for exemple from "c:\program files" to "c:\xxx" out off the program files folder

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on the application.xml,

[here is a link describing it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fe1)

Cheers !!

Comment: sorry but it's not the requirement, <installFolder> change only the folders inside "Program Files", but i want to change the default for exemple from "c:\program files" to "c:\xxx" out off the program files folder